# Where is the code that calculates shipping from origin

Tags: shipping

I need to find the code where the variable(s) of shipping origin location are declared and that calculates shipping rates so that I can create a module and manipulate the origin shipping address. Does anyone know where I can find this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shipping origin are managed form the `System->Configuration->Shipping Settings->Origin`.
These values are used in `Mage_Tax_Model_Calculation::getRateOriginRequest()`

```
public function getRateOriginRequest($store = null)
{
    $request = new Varien_Object();
    $request->setCountryId(Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Shipping_Model_Config::XML_PATH_ORIGIN_COUNTRY_ID, $store))
        ->setRegionId(Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Shipping_Model_Config::XML_PATH_ORIGIN_REGION_ID, $store))
        ->setPostcode(Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Shipping_Model_Config::XML_PATH_ORIGIN_POSTCODE, $store))
        ->setCustomerClassId($this->getDefaultCustomerTaxClass($store))
        ->setStore($store);
    return $request;
}
```

and in `Mage_Shipping_Model_Shipping::collectRates()`

```
public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
{
    $storeId = $request->getStoreId();
    if (!$request->getOrig()) {
        $request
            ->setCountryId(Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_STORE_COUNTRY_ID, $request->getStore()))
            ->setRegionId(Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_STORE_REGION_ID, $request->getStore()))
            ->setCity(Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_STORE_CITY, $request->getStore()))
            ->setPostcode(Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_STORE_ZIP, $request->getStore()));
    } 
    ....
}
```