# how to change shipping rates based on shipping origin

Tags: magento-enterprise, shipping

I want to calculate shipping rates and shipping methods based on shipping origin.
In Cart page shipping estimation and checkout page i want to calculate shipping charges based on different shipping origin locations.

I will have different shipping origins at cart page shipping estimation and checkout page after shipping address save.Now i want to pass dynamic shipping origins to calculate shipping charges.

any suggestions or ideas on where to start and how to get it.

**Update:**
I want same as [Where is the code that calculates shipping from origin](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5693/where-is-the-code-that-calculates-shipping-from-origin).

 but how to handle `getRateOriginRequest` and `Mage_Shipping_Model_Shipping::collectRates()`

**I Want to replace ship-from configuration fields dynamically in shipping estimation and checkout process**

Comment: Do you have your set up for multiple shipping origins ?

Comment: @Prateek Please check my updated question.

Comment: Event-observers and re-writes are 2 different approaches. Which one you want to use ?

Comment: I want to overwrite Mage_Tax_Model_Calculation::getRateOriginRequest and Mage_Shipping_Model_Shipping::collectRates()

Comment: There are plenty of articles about that on web, this is one of them : http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/. Is there any other problem you are facing ?

Comment: I have rewrite `getRateOriginRequest' and `CollectRates` but could not manage custom origin shipping address

Comment: By default, Magento doesn't allow the concept of multiple shipping origins. This is generally the concept of multi-dispatch locations modules. You'll have to build something like that yourself or you could try with some existing module.

Comment: For ups rates, I have also changed `Mage_Usa_Model_Shipping_Carrier_Ups` class `collectRates` method. now its working

Comment: If you have been able to resolve the issue completely, then please add it as an answer and accept it so that question doesn't add up in unanswered queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To modify any shipping rates information try to change on

```
Mage_Tax_Model_Calculation class and getRateOriginRequest method, 
Mage_Shipping_Model_Shipping` class and 'collectRates()
```

In my case i have configured only ups shipping method.

So here i need to change the code on

```
Mage_Usa_Model_Shipping_Carrier_Ups and collectRates method.
```

This class is executing after

```
Mage_Shipping_Model_Shipping class and collectRates()
```

Now i could change the ship-from information.